# Is RSA vulnerable to the padding oracle attack?

Tags: rsa, padding, padding-oracle

I know that AES in combination with CBC mode is vulnerable against the [Padding Oracle Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack). RSA also uses some kind of padding, hence can this attack be apply to RSA encrypted messages too?

Comment: You may be interested in [Bleichenbacher's attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12688/18376).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it's devastatingly effective, too. See [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding) and other RSA/asymmetric-function padding standards. OAEP is what you should use these days so far as I am aware. PKCS#1 has other defined padding schemes also (eg PSS, PKCS1.5), only some of which are effective.