# How can I securely encrypt the same message multiple times?

Tags: rsa

I want to encrypt the same message multiple times. I want to store the encrypted messages together. I've heard [if you do this with RSA, an attacker could decrypt the message with the Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://www.quaxio.com/exploring_three_weaknesses_in_rsa/).

What encryption methods do not suffer from this vulnerability? Would RSA with some random bits added to the message suffice?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt it multiple times? The most common case I know of is when you want multiple people to be able to read it, in which case a hybrid approach is standard.

Comment: Yeah – why do you encrypt _messages_ with RSA at all? Just generate completely different keys for each encryption, encrypt those _keys_ with RSA (or DH), and use the keys for AES-encrypting the message in three different ways.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, that is my case. I wasn't aware of the hybrid approach. Thanks!

Comment: @leftaroundabout Or just encrypt a single AES key three different times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, "RSA with some random bits added" does not suffice. There have been attacks against many of bad padding techniques for RSA. Instead a known secure mode of operation is required. The most well known secure mode is RSA-OAEP.

The earlier RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding may also be secure, but it has a well known attack against it called the [Bleichenbacher attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12688/1172). More to the point, there is also a [million messages attack](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3218) which shows one example what kind of attacks is possible if you just "add some random bits" to a message.

---

Note that the security argument of RSA-OAEP was under serious scrutiny. This has weakened but not broken the security proof for RSA-OAEP, which had to be adapted to the new situation. Furthermore, implementation mistakes may allow attacks against RSA-OAEP.

This is why there are some proponents here for RSA-KEM. Here RSA simply encrypts a random number in the range $[0, N)$, which is then fed into a key derivation function or KDF, which in turn creates a secret key which can be used for symmetric encryption. This is a rather elegant scheme which is provable secure, just like OAEP.

---

Note that the security proof for RSA-OAEP and RSA-KEM assumes that the RSA trapdoor itself is secure. However, that's something that cannot be proven - we just assume it is secure because it withstood all attempts so far.