# How does PKCS 1.5 solve the insecureness of Textbook RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa, padding

As we know, Textbook RSA is not enough safe to use because of the following issues;

- Guessable plaintext problem
- Small $e$ issue

I want to know how PKCS 1.5 solved these problems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PKCS#1 v1.5 describes a method (formally known as `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5`) that turns textbook RSA into a (heuristically) secure encryption scheme for small messages (PKCS#1 v1.5 also describes a signature scheme, which the question and this answer do not consider).

For a $k$-byte ($8k-7$ to $8k$-bit) public modulus part of public key $(N,e)$, the message to be encrypted $M$ is a $\mathrm{mLen}$-byte bytestring with $\mathrm{mLen}\le k-11$. Message $M$ is turned into
$\mathrm{EM}=\mathtt{0x00}\mathbin\|\mathtt{0x02}\mathbin\|\mathrm{PS}\mathbin\|\mathtt{0x00}\mathbin\|M$, where $\mathrm{PS}$ is drawn as a $k-\mathrm{mLen}-3$-byte bytestring consisting of fresh near-uniformly-random non-zero bytes. Then (with big-endian conversion between bytestring and  integer left implicit) the ciphertext is $C\gets\mathrm{EM}^e\bmod N$. That's textbook RSA encryption of $\mathrm{EM}$.

While plaintext $M$ might still be easily guessable, verifying such guess becomes much harder. A brute-force method becomes: try all the possible $\mathrm{PS}$ and compute the corresponding $C$, until one matches. That strategy requires $255^{k-\mathrm{mLen}-3}/2$ try on average (for each possible $M$). That's next to $2^{63}$ at least, and growing by a factor of $255$ for each byte of message capacity that we remove. That's believed to solve the *guessable plaintext problem*; but we have no formal proof that it does.

Thanks to $\mathtt{0x02}$ at the second byte of $\mathrm{EM}$, it holds that $\mathrm{EM}>2^{8k-15}$. It follows that for $e\ge3$, $\mathrm{EM}^e\gg N^2$ for all practical $k$, and that's more than enough to solve a number of *small $e$ issues* :

- any known extension of the $e^\text{th}$ root attack (in this attack against textbook RSA, where $C\gets M^e\bmod N$, it is used that for $M<N^{1/e}$, we can compute back $M$ from $C$ as $M\gets\sqrt[e]C$ )
- [Coppersmith's Short Pad Attack](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf#page=10) (which extends the Franklin-Reiter related messages attack to random padding).

`RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` also practically thwarts Hastad's broadcast attack. In this attack against textbook RSA, sending the same message to at least $e$ recipients allows decryption. The random $\mathrm{PS}$ makes $\mathrm{EM}$ for the same $M$ potentially different. Even for $e=3$, $\mathrm{PS}$ at the 8-byte minimum, and $2^{36}$ recipients of the same message $M$, probability that $e$ padded messages $\mathrm{EM}$ are identical is lower than one in a million, if I got the math right.

However, many `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` implementations are vulnerable when used with small $e$, such as $e=3$. That's because implementations often check that the first two bytes of $C^d\bmod N$ are $\mathtt{0x00}\mathbin\|\mathtt{0x02}$, and/or parse what follows in order to find the first $\mathtt{0x00}$, indicating the start of $M$ and allowing recovery of $\mathrm{mLen}$. When the result of such check is made available in a way leaking where the failure occurred (by a detailed error code, or timing, or some other side channel) to adversaries able to submit cryptograms for decryption, then [Bleichenbacher's padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12706/555) applies. It turns a moderate number of queries to a decrypting entity into an RSA private-key operation for arbitrary argument, allowing decryption of one message, or computing one signature if the same key is used for encryption and signature.

That's not a fatality, though: `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` padding can be checked in constant time, with a single error code regardless of the particular failure. Another possible strategy is to not check the left 10 bytes; or when $\mathrm{mLen}$ is known in advance, make no padding check and simply extract $M$ as the rightmost $\mathrm{mLen}$ bytes of $C^d\bmod N$.

Answer (score 10):

The Structure of PKCS#1 v1.5 as follows;

The message $m$ is padded to

```
x = 0x00 || 0x02 || r || 0x00 || m
```

and the ciphertext calculated as  $c=x^e\bmod N$ not by $m^e\bmod N$, where $r$ is a random string.

- Cube root attack cannot be applied since the padding guarantees that messages are not short.
- The random $r$ make the encryption probabilistic so that guessing the message $x$ has a very small probability. Two encryptions of a message $$\operatorname{Enc}_{k_{pub}}(m_1) \neq \operatorname{Enc}_{k_{pub}}(m_1)$$ due to randomization.
- Also, the padding scheme prohibits the malleability property of RSA, that is

$$ \operatorname{Enc}_{k_{pub}}(2) \cdot c = \operatorname{Enc}_{k_{pub}}(2) \cdot \operatorname{Enc}_{k_{pub}}(m) = \operatorname{Enc}_{k_{pub}}(2\cdot m)$$

Comment: It is guessing the _padded_ message `x` that has a small probability. Independently: there's more than a single _small e issue_, only one is covered by this answer.