# PKCS RSA - Why do we need encoding

Tags: rsa, signature, encoding, pkcs1

In the RSASSA-PKCS-v1_5 signature scheme, the first step is to perform an encoding on the hashed data. (0x00||0x01||PS||0x00||T).

Is this encoding important for security ? What happens if the hash is directly encrypted without encoding ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does PKCS 1.5 solve the insecureness of Textbook RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66722/how-does-pkcs-1-5-solve-the-insecureness-of-textbook-rsa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per section 9 of the [paper](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9), the encoding used is required for the security of the scheme.

> The encoding operation may introduce some randomness, so that
> different applications of the encoding operation to the same message
> will produce different encoded messages, which has benefits for
> provable security.  For such an encoding method, both an encoding and
> a verification operation are needed unless the verifier can reproduce
> the randomness (e.g., by obtaining the salt value from the signer).
> For a deterministic encoding method only an encoding operation is
> needed.

> Two encoding methods for signatures with appendix are employed in the
> signature schemes and are specified here: EMSA-PSS and EMSA-PKCS1-
> v1_5.

The paper then goes into further detail on these two encoding methods.

You would be compromising the security proof of the scheme if you did not use the encoding, however you could feasibly apply the encoding after hashing the message.  Per the paper:

> Without compromising the security proof for RSASSA-PSS, one may
> perform steps 1 and 2 of EMSA-PSS-ENCODE and EMSA-PSS-VERIFY (the
> application of the hash function to the message) outside the
> module that computes the rest of the signature operation, so that
> mHash rather than the message M itself is input to the module.  In
> other words, the security proof for RSASSA-PSS still holds even if
> an opponent can control the value of mHash.

The fabulous answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51680/is-the-rsa-signature-attack-from-desmedt-and-odlyzko-practical?rq=1) goes into detail regarding one attack the encoding prevents, and provides links to other attacks on wide deterministic RSA signature signature schemes.

Section 2 of the original [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810025803/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/P1363a/contributions/pss-submission.pdf) by Bellare & Rogaway outlines several advantages of the encoding scheme.