# Is it more secure to use Diffie-Hellman to generate a symmetric AES key for use with CBC, rather than use CBC directly atop RSA encryption?

Tags: encryption, rsa, diffie-hellman, cbc

## Short question:

If we assume a one-session use public RSA keypair on both sides, and if we assume that the input stream will be split into blocks -- with CBC encryption -- is there any security disadvantage to encrypting the blocks directly with the RSA asymmetric key rather than deriving a symmetric AES key using DH and using that?

I understand that hybrid encryption using an AES symmetric key is faster than encrypting every block with RSA.  And I understand that using hybrid encryption with a DH-derived AES key might be more secure than pure RSA is if you *also* hash-ratchet the AES key to provide forward secrecy.

But if we ignore hash ratcheting and forward secrecy, for a given stream is DH-AES actually more secure than just encrypting every message with RSA?  I don't think it is, but I want to confirm.

## Longer question:

If we assume:

1. A symmetric (such as AES) encryption function `symEncrypt(K,M)` that can encrypt `M`-byte blocks with key `K`, with a matching `symDecrypt(K,M)` function that decrypts the results, such that `M = symDecrypt(K, symEncrypt(K, M))`
2. An asymmetric (such as RSA) encryption function `asymEncrypt(K.pub,M)` that can can also encrypt `M`-byte blocks with a public key `K.pub`, with a matching `asymDecrypt(K.priv,M)` function that decrypts the result with the private key `K.priv`, such that `M = asymDecrypt(K.priv, asymEncrypt(K.pub, M))`
3. Two parties, Alice and Bob, each of whom have generated one-session-use asymmetric keypairs `Alice.pub/priv` and `Bob.pub/priv` respectively, and have exchanged those public keys with each other
4. A plaintext message split up into a series of `M`-byte sized blocks, `P[0]...P[n]`, that Alice wants to send Bob in a secure fashion, over an insecure network

Is there any security difference between:

### Hybrid Encryption:

A ciphertext message constructed using CBC atop AES symmetric encryption using a Diffie-Hellman derived key:

1. Alice derives a secret key from her private key and Bob's public key: `K = Diffie-Hellman(Alice.priv,Bob.pub)`
2. Alice encrypts the first block using a predetermined IV, and sends it to Bob: `C[0] = symEncrypt(K, P[0] ^ IV)`
3. Alice encrypts the second block using the first cihperblock, and sends it to Bob: `C[1] = symEncrypt(K, P[1] ^ C[0])`
4. ... and so on for all n blocks
5. Bob derives the same secret key that Alice did, using Bob's private key and Alice's public key: `K = Diffie-Hellman(Bob.priv,Alice.pub)`
6. Bob decrypts the first block using the predetermined IV: `P[0] = symDecrypt(K, C[0]) ^ IV`
7. Bob decrypts the second block using the first cipherblock: `P[1] = symDecrypt(K, C[1]) ^ C[0]`
8. ... and so on for all n blocks

### Pure Asymmetric Encryption:

A ciphertext message constructed using CBC atop RSA asymmetric encryption:

1. Alice encrypts the first block using a predetermined IV, and sends it to Bob: `C[0] = asymEncrypt(Bob.pub, P[0] ^ IV)`
2. Alice encrypts the second block using the first cihperblock, and sends it to Bob: `C[1] = asymEncrypt(Bob.pub, P[1] ^ C[0])`
3. ... and so on for all n blocks
4. Bob decrypts the first block using the predetermined IV: `P[0] = asymDecrypt(Bob.priv, C[0]) ^ IV`
5. Bob decrypts the second block using the first cipherblock: `P[1] = asymDecrypt(Bob.priv, C[1]) ^ C[0]`
6. ... and so on for all n blocks

I *think* in every practical sense they will be equivalently secure.  (Sure, maybe one will take a thousand years to crack, and the other two thousand years, but both are effectively secure for real world use.)

It's not more secure to derive a shared AES symmetric session key using
Diffie-Hellman and encrypt a message with that, than to just encrypt a message with a RSA public key and decrypt it with the corresponding private key, is it?

Comment: Short answer: Use TLS?

Comment: What kind of RSA encryption does `asymEncrypt` use? Textbook RSA? RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5? RSAES-OAEP? Is the matching `asymDecrypt` secure against [Bleichenbacher-style attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12688/555)? How secure is the generation of the "one-session use public RSA keypair" against side-channel and key-guessing attacks? How does the matching public key become trusted (there could be protocol attacks on that)?