# CCA-Attacks in the real (and digital) world

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, history

Is any concrete and real examples of CCA-attacks in recent history.
I'm aware about examples of WW2, but I'm more interested to modern examples in a digital context (for example against OFB, CBC).

Comment: The most famous CCA attack in a digital context is the padding oracle attack.

Comment: There's [Bleichenbacher's attack on PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12688/555).